# ClojureScript and closure: how to protect attributes from being renamed by closure

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to to some HTML5 canvas drawing and I ran across a problem with the advanced compilation mode. I would like to exemplify this with the `mozDash` property of Mozilla browsers (although this question is quite generic on the attribute optimization feature) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Gecko-specific_attributes

The javascript `canvas.mozDash = ...` code can be expressed as [1] `(set! (.-mozDash canvas) ...)` or [2] `(aset canvas "mozDash" ...)` in Clojurescript.

I had used [1]  before and it worked in most cases, however with the `mozDash` attribute the `mozDash` identifier is gone in the advanced compilation result. Therefore I tried [2] and it seems that the `mozDash` identifier is retained using the `aset` variant.

My questions therefore are:

- Is this an intended difference of these notations?
- Why is the behaviour different ([1] and [2] work) for `(.-fillStyle canvas)`?

I kind of suspect that standard HTML properties are protected by default while not-standard properties (like `mozDash`) is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closure compiler is allowed to rename directly accessed attributes that aren't specified in externs or exports.

See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames

Specifically, `(aset x "y" z)` translates to `x["y"] = z`, which is exempt from minimizing, while `(set! (.-y x) z)` translates to `x.y = z` and can be minimized unless x.y is specified as extern or exported.

I would assume that the mozDash property isn't specified in the externs file(s) you're using for Canvas.

Comment: Indeed, I have also found https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojurescript/uO3MLafNnZ4/G2D5PE6eoqQJ being a recent discussion on the mailing list about this.