# What is the ClojureScript analogue of setting an object value that didn't exist to null from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I'm seeing lots of code using the pattern:

```
if (typeof a.b === 'undefined') {
  a.b = null;
```

Now I'm translating this to:

```
(if (not (exists (.-b a)))
  (aset a b nil)
```

But I feel like I should be setting this to:

```
(if (not (exists (.-b a)))
  (aset a b (clj->js {}))
```

(Because the compiler may eliminate the step entirely in the former case).

Is that appropriate - or am I losing some crucial data?

My question is: **What is the ClojureScript analogue of setting an object value that didn't exist to null from JavaScript?**

Comment: What would the purpose of this code be? `undefined` and `null` are not that different in most cases.

Comment: You're defining a key with a null value that didn't exist before. My concern was that Clojurescript, unlike js, would optimise this operation away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if attempting to imitate some JavaScript, I'd recommend the [:repl-verbose](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/REPL-options#repl-verbose) option, as it makes it very easy to try variants at the REPL and immediately see the resulting JavaScript.

If you want to exactly imitate your code, then `set!` will do the trick:

```
(when (not (exists? (.-b js/a)))
  (set! (.-b js/a) nil))
```

produces

```
((!(typeof a.b !== 'undefined'))?a.b = null:null)
```

But (and perhaps this is the same as the concern raised over compiler behavior), to avoid renaming during Closure optimizations (see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144429/clojurescript-and-closure-how-to-protect-attributes-from-being-renamed-by-closu)), `aget` and `aset` can be used with a string-based index:

```
(when (not (exists? (aget js/a "b")))
  (aset js/a "b" nil))

((!(typeof (a["b"]) !== 'undefined'))?(a["b"] = null):null)
```